# Passing json file into Hashtable<String, String>

Tags: java, json, hashtable

I have passed json file into `Hashtable<String, String> params`:

```
{Date=2015-05-01, Data1={"Id":"1","Seating":0,"IdServiceCode":"8"}}
```

It's straightforward to read data into strings (`String st = params.get("Date")`). But I want to save `Date` as GregorianCalendar and Data1 as Hashtable. How can I do this?

```
public double getEstimation(Hashtable<String, String> params) 
{
  GregorianCalendar cal = params.get("Date");
  Hashtable<String, String> data = params.get("Data1");
  //...
}
```

Comment: I suppose you do have a library to parse JSON, don't you?

Comment: @user3159253: Please see an update. I'm working with Hashtable<String, String> params that was created on base of json.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos how did you create that Hashtable?

Comment: Can you please specify what library are you using to parse the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must parse your date string into a date object and create a table based on your JSON.

Given that you are using JSON.org, this should do:

```
public double getEstimation(Hashtable<String, String> params) {
    // not sure if date is in this format
    SimpleDateFormat sdt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = sdt.parse(params.get("Date"));
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(date);

    HashTable<String, String> data = jsonStringToHT(params.get("Data1"));
    //...
}

private HashTable<String, String> jsonStringToHT(String json){
    HashTable<String, String> ht = new HashTable<String, String>();
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(t);
    Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

    while( keys.hasNext() ){
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        String value = jObject.getString(key); 
        ht.put(key, value);

    }
    return ht;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have both `Date` and `Hashtable` as values in your `Hashtable`, then it should have type of `Hashtable<String, Object>`. It is however easier to use a library object like [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getNames%28org.json.JSONObject%29). You can construct it from JSON using constructor `JSONObject(java.lang.String source)`. It has methods like `getJSONObject` which will return another `JSONOBject` (which is a kind of table) for your `Data1` key. It doesn't have built in get function for dates, so you will have to `getString` and write the conversion yourself

Answer (score 0):

Firstly [Use this library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107)

Then parse this string 
JSONObject job =new JSONObject("yourJsonString");

**Note :(yourJsonString) It's a string not your hashTable**

String date=job.getString("date");  //This will give you date in string format

Now use your GregorianCalendar API to convert your string into Date.

Answer (score 0):

For JSON (Using org.json library):

```
String str = "{ \"Id\": \"1\", \"Seating\": \"0\", \"IdServiceCode\": \"8\" }";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
Hashtable<String, String> data = new Hashtable<String, String>();
data.put ("Id",obj.getString("Id"));
data.put ("Seating",obj.getString("Seating"));
data.put ("IdServiceCode",obj.getString("IdServiceCode"));
```

For Date :

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");
Date date = df.parse("2015-05-01");
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(date);
```